# passing a scanner object to a method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

If I pass a scanner object to a method, will the scanner scan from the beginning of the input or continued to scan for the remaining part of the input. Here is my code:

```
public class Test {
  public void test(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(str);

    Test t = new Test(sc);
    t.test();
  }
}

// here is the input file:
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
```

I have test this code on both on Windows and Linux, but I got two different result

The first result is in the method test, it print 5 6 7 8

the second result is difficult to understand, it print 1 2 3 4, still the first line of the input.

Is this related to the different version of Java, Can someone explain this for me, thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by return carriage?

Comment: `\n` is a carriage return character

Comment: how is the return carriage difference will effect this result?

Comment: `how is the return carriage difference will effect this result?` it won't however, the code you supplied won't even compile

Comment: That's not the problem. `public test(sc)` is neither a proper method definition nor a proper constructor for this class.

Comment: Have you added `System.out.println(str);` to `main()` after the 1st try and before the second?

Comment: Ray, alaska has changed it to public void test() means its a function. But her main code is still calling parameterised constructor which is non existent.

Comment: @Ravi: Good catch. Do I leave the comment as sort of 'thread history' then?

Comment: One more intriguing thing about this code is that, it says "here is the input file" but in fact her program is reading console(system.in) and not file which will definitely change the output because the moment you hit enter it will display output straight and not wait for next line input.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi that is not a problem, just use command line "cat input.txt | java Test"

Answer (score 1):

The scanner is the same object in both methods - you're passing around references to the same scanner. So, it has no clue it's being used from a new place in the program - it will faithfully do the same thing no matter what code is using it if the same methods are called.

Comment: In my understanding, I pass the references to the method, so that, there is only one object. So that, if I call nextLine in the test method, I should get the second line of the file, right?

Comment: @alaska The scanner will pick off where it was, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in your code >> Test t = new Test(sc). It uses parameterised constructor but I don't see any.

```
Q. if I pass a scanner object to a method, will the scanner scan from the beginning of
the input or continued to scan for the remaining part of the input ?
```

In Java, Objects are passed by Ref(reference to object heap address) not by values(as in primitive types). And that is why passing an Object to a function does not change the Object. The Object remains the same.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: actually, I think java is pass by value, however, since most variables in java is object, it is actually pass the copy of the object reference to the method.

Comment: this is the same as pass a pointer in c or c++. If you modify the object in the subroutine, the global object should also changed. Because in fact, we only has one object

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'change', if one assigns a new value to a method local reference, the original value is unchanged; however, if one adds an item to a method local reference of an ArrayList, for instance, the 'original' ArrayList will contain the new value.

Comment: The value you are talking about is called Object's heap value. It is actually called reference to object in the heap.

Comment: @RayStojonic, You are right, ray. But my talk was in the given context.

Comment: yes, you are right. But in this case, the two scanner are referring to the same object, right?

Comment: @Ravi: Fair enough, just trying to be clear. (think I fell short though...)

Comment: Yes, its the same Scanner object.

Comment: @alaska - +1 for making this distinction. A lot of people have the misconception that Java uses [_call-by-reference_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) when it is in fact passing _references_ by value, just as it does with the primitive types. (If Java really supported call-by-reference then you could use the references as "out parameters".)

Comment: @DaoWen, the value you are talking about is actually reference to object heap address.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi - Yes, I know. The point I wanted to make is that passing a reference to an object by value isn't the same as pass-by-reference. Since _pass-by-reference_ has a very specific technical meaning, rather than saying that objects are "passed by reference in Java" it would be more clear to say something like "in Java you pass references to objects..."

Comment: @DaoWen, Yes, my answer was confusing. Changed it. You are right, passbyref and passbyval both have different meanings when it comes to technical specification.

Comment: +1 for both alaska and Dao for pointing out passbyref - passbyval thing

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to [the break line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_break_%28computing%29).

A new line is defined in a different manner from one OS to another. If you print the value of

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

You will see the value of the property is not the same in Windows and Linux.

I do not know where did you write your input file but it probably contain an OS specific line separator. When you run your program on another OS, you would end but a different result.

I suggest that you define the delimiters of your scanner file like this

```
sc .useDelimiter("\n|\r\n");
```

If I am not mistaken, **\n** represents the linux new line while  **\r\n** represents the windows new line.